# unable to switch version of node from 8 to 10 on mac

Tags: node.js

I tried various options available over the internet as listed below, but still node v8 is there even though I restarted my system as well-

```
 sudo npm install n -g

 sudo n stable

 npm install -g n

 sudo npm cache clean -f sudo npm install -g n sudo n stable

 brew update brew upgrade brew upgrade node

 brew update && brew upgrade node && npm update -g npm

 sudo npm cache clean -f sudo npm install -g n

 sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node
 /opt/local/lib/node_modules sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
 /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d

 brew uninstall --force node brew unlink node brew install node@10
```

Comment: When you type "which node" into the terminal what path is returned?  Does that path match where you are downloading the newer version of node?  If not, update your PATH variable to point to the newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to switch node versions, you can use the install script directly, restart the shell and start using it like:

```
nvm install <node_version>
```

if you want to get the list of available versions you can:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

if you want to see what versions has already been installed:

```
nvm ls
```

to switch a version is:

```
nvm use <node_version> # the version should be already installed using nvm install
```

and to set up a default version you can alias it like this:

nvm alias default

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice one, it's working. Thanks @sebastian
I found one more link which could be helpful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps

Can you please guide me, why other commands didn't work for me?

Comment: the commands I've tried and already mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS with nvm installed. I was trying to change node from 10 to 12.

In my case, `nvm use *.*` didn't work.
It used to work once with `nvm use 10`, but later when I needed to switch to Node 12, `nvm use 12` didn't work for me like other attempts to change.

So the steps that helped:

1. `which -a node` showed me that I have multiple paths to the node:

``

```
/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.7/bin/node
/opt/local/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

2. I have commented out (removed) the line with the unwanted path `/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin` in the files:

`~/.bash_profile`

`~/.zshrc`

3. Step 2 unfrozen the `nvm use [version]` command on my Mac.

Maybe it help someone.